# How to concatenate strings in Sightly/HTL?

Tags: sightly

I have the following code:

```
<sly data-sly-use.link="${'core.impl.view.tools.LinkUtils' @ path=properties.targetURL}"></sly>
```

I want to concatenate `properties.linkType` to `properties.targetURL`.

Any ideas how it can be done? I've found examples on the net but they don't seem to work for my situation.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That depends on what kind of string concatenation you have in mind:

1. Concatenating strings using an operator is **not supported**, ie. you cannot do <strike>`${properties.targetURL + properties.linkType}`</strike>. A workaround (suggested by @Jens) is to do something like: `<sly data-sly-test.concatenated="${'{0}{1}' @ format=[properties.targetURL, properties.linkType]}"></sly>`
2. Concatenating strings in HTML output can be done by placing HTL expression next to each other, ie. `${properties.targetUrl}${properties.linkType}`
3. Sending both strings to an Use Object is supported via multiple expression options: `<sly data-sly-use.link="${'core.impl.view.tools.LinkUtils' @ path=properties.targetURL, type=properties.linkType}"></sly>`
4. Concatenating strings to form an URL might be possible in some cases using [URI Manipulation](https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#125-uri-manipulation)

Comment: There is another option which is not really useful but for sake of completeness: `${'{0}{1}' @ format=[properties.string1, properties.string2]}`. See https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/htl-spec/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md#examples

Comment: @Jens, that is very creative especially if combined with `data-sly-test`

Comment: I was thinking about a workaround using `data-sly-test` as well, but I am not sure you can use `format` with `data-sly-test`. If so, you could create a new concatenated string which in turn can be used in the statement the ops wants to use it in.

Answer (score 14):

I just want to add one more way to concatenate strings to the above answer, by using `@ join`.

```
<sly data-sly-test="${['String1','String2','String3'] @ join = '-'}"/>
```

It will give output as:
    `String1-String2-String3`

Comment: Can you send me full syntax, what you are writing

Comment: looks like it was my mistake, I was using wrong context, that's why this `join = ' ` wasn't working, so I take it back what I wrote, everything in ok